Grouping single band raster values so that groups have the same total
I have a single band raster and I need to visualise areas that total the same. In other words aggregate the pixels into a number of groups that each have the same total value according to the sum of the values in the original raster. This is similar to maps like Canada divided into four regions of equal populations and one option I have tried is converting pixels to polygons and using gatpkg on the shapefile. It works, but it's slow and I have to substantially reduce the resolution of the raster or it would take too long.
What I would like is a way to do this on the raster, so taking the pixel values and their geographic similarity and grouping them together (I guess by assigning integer group values on another raster of the same resolution) until they equal a certain value that I set or a total number of groups of equal value is reached. Has anyone done something like this before and is there a package or an algorithm already?

Build Balanced Zones in ArcGIS does the same thing as gatpkg but is a LOT quicker. Still need to covert to vector though.

Grouping Analysis?
